# Only fetch categories that are related to a minimum of entries

Tags: categories, relations

Is there a way to only fetch categories that have been assigned to a minimum of entries, i.e. `4`?

Currently I fetch categories like this:

```
{% set productIds = craft.entries.section('products').ids() %}
{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo({ sourceElement: productIds }) %}
```

I know I can now do the following to only display content for categories which have been assigned to at least  four entries:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo(category) %}
{% if entries|length > 4 %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

But is there a way to apply this logic to the `craft.categories` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: There is no way to apply this sort of logic to the `craft.categories` query. The way I have set this up is good. It can be improved performance wise by wrapping the queries around a `{% cache %}` tag.

As Carl has pointed out in [his answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/11159/176), the matching categories could also be merged into an array and added to a new query, which could then be used for pagination etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you can always do in situations, where the default parameters are not enough,
is to "collect" element IDs and pass them to the `id` param of a new criteria model.

So loop through all categories and merge the category IDs matching you condition to an array:

```
{% set topCategoriesIds = mainCategoriesIds|merge([category.id]) %}
```

When you're done, get your filtered categories from these IDs:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.id(topCategoriesIds) %}
```

Comment: Thank you Carl. I don't fully follow. How does that give me categories that are related to equal or more than 4 entries? If I understand correctly, this still creates an extra loop and query, so performance wise there is no gain to my original way, is there?

Comment: No, it is really the same to your idea, so no performance gains at all. The only difference is, that you can now query for them with a single criteria model. I thought that's what you needed, as this allows you to paginate the results or do other things not possible when having the conditional in your "output loop".

Comment: That makes sense and am sure would come in very handy in other scenarios. For my current situation, I was looking to see if there was a way to adapt the `craft.categories` query so that I didn't have to create an additional entries query and loop.

Comment: No, unfortunatelly there's no way to add your custom conditional to the `relatedTo` param in your query. What about wrapping the output loop in `cache` tags? How is your PHP/MySQL knowledge, you could write a custom plugin to get them with a single query from the database?

Comment: Yes, definitely a good call on the caching. My PHP knowledge is limited. I could maybe dabble something together, but it isn't absolutely necessary right now and am happy to use what I've got. Thanks for your ideas :)